# Auth user not added

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This code is work fine but when i use auth::id than show error like this in api Message unauthenticated

API

```
Route::post('/friend', 'FriendController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

Working code

```html
 public function index(Request $request) {
       
        $sender = Friend::where('sender_id', $request->sender_id)->where('receiver_id',$request->receiver_id)->first();
        if(empty($sender)){
            Friend::create(['sender_id'=>$request->sender_id,'receiver_id'=>$request->receiver_id, 'approved'=>'pending']);
            
            $response = ['message'=>'Friend Request has been sent','status'=>200];
            
        }else{
            $response = ['message'=>'Request has been sent already','status'=>200];
         
        }
        return response()->json($response);
        
    }
```

Not working code, error message unauthenticated

```html
public function index(Request $request) {
       //$user = Auth::user()->id;
        $sender = Friend::where('sender_id', $request->Auth::user()->id)->where('receiver_id',$request->receiver_id)->first();
        if(empty($sender)){
            Friend::create(['sender_id'=>$request->Auth::user()->id,'receiver_id'=>$request->receiver_id, 'approved'=>'pending']);
            
            $response = ['message'=>'Friend Request has been sent','status'=>200];
            
        }else{
            $response = ['message'=>'Request has been sent already','status'=>200];
         
        }
        return response()->json($response);
        
    }
```

How can i add sender_id is authenticated user id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auth()->id()
```

or

```
$request->user()->id
```

This will give you id of loggedin User

Also check your middleware it should be

```
->middleware('auth:api')
```

Comment: @Kinnu123 are you using JWT tokens ?

Comment: no login time generate token i used, i use passport package for login and register api -@Muhammad Faran Ali

Comment: Can you share your api guards config from config/auth.php

Comment: 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            
        ],
    ],

Comment: @Kinnu123 everything is fine, You might need to clear you cache, and do composer dumpautoload

Comment: I try but not work thats why i posted question? -@Muhammad Faran Ali

Comment: I think you must have checkout your headers

Comment: @Kinnu123 Are you sending Authorization: Bearer {{access token}}

Comment: @Kinnu123 also check your token expiry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204922/discussion-between-muhammad-faran-ali-and-kinnu123).

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `$request->Auth::user()->id` to get the id of authenticated user ., Instead use this directly to get id.

```
Auth::user()->id
```

Code :

```
public function index(Request $request) {
       //$user = Auth::user()->id;
        $sender = Friend::where('sender_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('receiver_id',$request->receiver_id)->first();
        if(empty($sender)){
            Friend::create(['sender_id'=>Auth::user()->id,'receiver_id'=>$request->receiver_id, 'approved'=>'pending']);

            $response = ['message'=>'Friend Request has been sent','status'=>200];

        }else{
            $response = ['message'=>'Request has been sent already','status'=>200];

        }
        return response()->json($response);

    }
```

Comment: I try that...but its not working, error show message unauthenticated in postman -@farooq

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
$request->Auth::user()->id
```

to

```
Auth::user()->id
```